# Columns into JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I have the following table:

| Name | Pets |
| --- | --- |
| John | Bird |
| John | Cow |
| John | Dog |
| Nina | Cow |
| Nina | Fish |
| Nina | Cat |

I would like to output it like so:

| Name | Pets |
| --- | --- |
| John | ["Bird","Cow","Dog"] |
| Nina | ["Cow","Fish","Cat"] |

I have this starting point, that converts a single column to JSON.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',')) AS names 
FROM table_name;
```

I'm new to working with arrays and JSON in SQL. Is this possible? What is the best solution?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: I actually need the same solution for all 3 database systems :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is already a proper solution for this current case, just need to add `GROUP BY` expression, and exchange the aliases such as

```sql
SELECT name, JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(pets)) AS pets 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY name
```

where `,` is the default seperator, then adding that is redundant

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8cc62e9a48bdea5212ca55fcd3cb8e26)</kbd>

P.S. seems your DB is **MySQL** (version at least **5.7+**) or its extension which's so called **MariaDB** or **SQLite**. It's expected to tag the DBMS, and its version, which you're using.

Comment: Thanks enormously! Your wisdom is deeply appreciated! 

Comment: You're welcome @Martin Andersen , have a nice study!